# Why cant I access my website/subdomain through nginx?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I currently have two docker containers, both are frontends that I can manually access by going to : of each respective docker container, running `docker ps` i can see them:

```
bb9694c2ee02   webapp:latest        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   34 minutes ago   Up 34 minutes   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp               webapp
7d302b7c92ac   oldfrontend:legacy   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   40 minutes ago   Up 40 minutes   3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32769->9876/tcp, :::32769->9876/tcp   legacy_frontend
```

In `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` I have two .conf files along with the default:

website.com.conf:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     website.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

}
```

and then the other for the subdomain, sub.website.com:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     sub.website.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:9876;
        }
}
```

I have confirmed that nginx is running, and no errors are present in the logs, even after restarting nginx. I have also checked that ufw is allowing traffic on ports 3000 and 9876, and I am able to visit these from the : they're hosted on, but when i try to go to `website.com` it doesnt respond. Before, when I didnt run nginx and just had the docker container mapping port 3000->80, it was working. Why isnt NGINX letting me connect? I didn't see anything in the access logs either. Additionally, trying to just connect to the ip (without specifying the port) doesnt respond either.

**Edit A**
Running `ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled` I get the output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Jan 15 00:28 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jan 15 01:00 legacy.whati.me.conf -> ../sites-available/sub.website.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jan 15 00:59 whati.me.conf -> ../sites-available/website.conf
```

and `sudo nginx -t` yields:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```